# How to set multiple users in Amazon RDS for SQL 2012?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

How  to set multiple users in Amazon RDS for SQL 2012? I have created an account using my email account authentication and my developer is asking my email account credentials to deploy the database in the Amazon. Is it possible  to establish SQL 2012 in the Amazon without sharing my email credentials?

Comment: I see that you added a reference to email credentials. That doesn't clarify anything. The two options are AWS credentials or database credentials.

Comment: Well email credential is about AWS Credential. We provide our email account to create AWS Credential to set up the account. I have created database credentials separately and shared with the developer. It works.

Comment: Read my updated answer. You need AWS training or a consultant to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give users access to the AWS infrastructure you use [AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/iam/) to create a user with whatever privileges they need. You can give just access to one database if you like, read only or read/write, it's very fine grained.

Alternately you can use standard SQL Server users if you just want them to have database access, that way they don't need an AWS login at all.

**Update to "email" comment above.**
No, "email credentials" are credentials for you email account. Any email address associated with your amazon account is the root account, and no, you don't give that to anyone, ever, and you [shouldn't be using it yourself](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/root-vs-iam.html). You need to use IAM to create yourself a power user account, and create an account for your developer with appropriate access.

I suggest you need to follow some basic AWS best practices, if you're going to use the platform you're probably going to need some training. Right now you're probably vulnerable to a host of problems or situations involving loss of the account, loss of data, or at the extreme end poor control can result in you having someone take over your account since you seem willing to give people access to the root account.

Comment: Thank you @Tim, I understand the SQL level Authentication. Now to establish the Database connection for the first time, do i need to share my account details.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want your user to administer the database (start, stop, change instance size, create SQL server users) or do you just want them to connect to the database instance to load data? Please edit your question to clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Great..explaination.. Thank you so much Tim. I will have my IAM account and go through that